# How to combine the "conda create" parameters "--file", "--prefix" and "--copy"?

Tags: anaconda, conda

I would like to create a conda environment based on an environment file in a certain path, using no symlinks. Therefore, I would like to run the following conda command:

```
conda create --file environment.yml --prefix ./python --copy
```

the file `environment.yml` looks like this (I shortened it):

```
name: null
channels:
- defaults
dependencies:
- python==3.7.0
```

However, I get the following error:

```
CondaValueError: could not parse 'name: null' in: environment.yml
```

The following command works:

```
conda env create --file environment.yml --prefix ./python
```

However, then I cannot use the `--copy` parameter:

```
error: unrecognized arguments: --copy
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I agree that there really should be an option for this, you can temporarily set the `copy_always` configuration option to true while you run the command and that should do the trick:

```
CONDA_COPY_ALWAYS=1 conda env create --file environment.yml --prefix ./python
```

To verify, I created two versions of the same env with and without `CONDA_COPY_ALWAYS=1`. They both come out as 969 MB in `du` alone, but only the one without the `CONDA_COPY_ALWAYS=1` gets reduced when including `miniconda3/pkgs` in the `du`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. However, if I just copy and paste your command, I obviously get an error because CONDA_COPY_ALWAYS is no recognized command. Unfortunately, I could not find anything about CONDA_COPY_ALWAYS on Google. Is it an environment variable? Please elaborate a little.

Comment: @Nos yes, it's an environment variable, so use whatever syntax your shell accepts to temporarily set it. All Conda configuration variables (`conda config --describe`) can also be set as environment vars (see [this post](https://www.anaconda.com/conda-configuration-engine-power-users/)).