# Creating a conda environment from .yml without links

Tags: apache-spark, conda

is it possible to create a conda environment from a .yml file without any link?

I tried

```
conda env create --copy -f myenv.yml
```

but --copy goes as an unrecognized argument

```
conda env create -f myenv.yml
```

and then

```
conda create --name myenv_cloned --copy --clone myenv
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

This would be particularly useful in Spark, where environments need to be built and passed to worker nodes with no links. .yml files are a typical way to exchange environments.

Comment: What do you mean by _link_ ?

Comment: I mean without using any hard or soft link (it's what the option --copy is for): it means that you create all the packages inside the folder of your environment and you don't put a link to an external source (as it usually happens to save space).

Comment: What is this for, by the way?

Comment: When you use Spark you need to pass environments with no links to the worker nodes. It looks difficult to create such an environment from a .yml, however .yml files are a common way to pass and build environments.

Comment: What happens when you try `conda create --name myenv_cloned --copy --clone myenv` ?

Comment: While `conda-env create` does not have a `--copy` flag, it may still abide by the configuration setting `always_copy`. Perhaps try setting this temporarily while running the command, e.g., `CONDA_ALWAYS_COPY=TRUE conda env create -f myenv.yml`.

Comment: In digging around for information on this I feel like I know less than before, I'm going to try to raise an issue in the Conda repo about this, and the `--file` argument to `conda create`.

Comment: @merv sorry for the long wait... I tried what you suggested but it did not work.

Comment: @AMC any news from the conda people?

Comment: @spec3 Unfortunately, I had forgotten to contact them, my apologies. On another note, I just tried `conda create --name myenv_cloned --copy --clone myenv`, and it seems to work fine. What happens when you try that method?

Comment: @spec3 strange because I just found an old answer where I verified that setting the environment variable works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58278326/570918

Comment: @AMC I simply get an environment without links. I will try to figure out whether there are some strange settings on the machine I'm on...

Comment: @merv that's weird... I will try to figure out whether there are some strange settings on the machine I'm on...

Comment: @spec3 _simply get an environment without links._ Is that not the goal, though?

Comment: @AMC I have a workaround for this issue that is not using yml. I would like to find a way to use it though.

Comment: @spec3 I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Creating the environment from the yml file and then cloning it works, but you want to find a solution which is more straightforward/direct?